# Как записать/читать свой класс в qt через WinApi?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

К примеру у меня есть свой класс noteitem с полями различных типов (QTime, QDatetime, QString, и так далее). Я хочу с помощью WinApiшных функций WriteFile и Readfile произвести запись в файл/чтение из файла массива (вектора) с моими собственными объектами класса noteitem. Вопрос, каким образом можно это сделать? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Какой ответ, кроме "пишите поэлементно и так же читайте" вы ждете? С конкретным кодом для неизвестного класса?

Comment: Как и при записи/чтения, например, в БД - все "сложные" типы приводятся к базовым типам данных. Например QDateTime или QTime к строковому представлению, или к целому времени в миллисекундах от какой-то "абсолютной" точки отсчета. QString имеет функцию c_str() которая возвращает строку в стиле С (с нулевым символом в конце), для симметрии имеется соответствующий конструктор и так далее. Так же можно хранить и бинарный слепок данных как есть. Короче, варианты имеются, выбирайте и пробуйте

Comment: Для классов которые работают с `QDataStream` можно загнать данные в `QBuffer` и оттуда `WriteFile`, чтение в обратном порядке. Классы полученные из `QObject` врядли по простому получится писать/читать